# ember server frontend/app.js: undefined is not a function

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am a newbie to ember. Running ember server command gives me "frontend/app.js: undefined is not a function" error. I have ran npm install and bower install.

```
version: 0.2.1
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/#watchman for more info.
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
File: frontend/app.js
frontend/app.js: undefined is not a function
TypeError: frontend/app.js: undefined is not a function
at Object.isValidIdentifier (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/types/validators.js:176:44)
at TraversalPath.Property (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/transformation/transformers/es3/property-literals.js:16:58)
at TraversalPath.call (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/traversal/path.js:127:26)
at TraversalPath.visit (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/traversal/path.js:142:10)
at TraversalContext.visitNode (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/traversal/context.js:34:22)
at TraversalContext.visit (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/traversal/context.js:51:28)
at Function.traverse.node (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/traversal/index.js:44:17)
at TraversalPath.visit (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/traversal/path.js:159:18)
at TraversalContext.visitNode (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/traversal/context.js:34:22)
at TraversalContext.visit (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/traversal/context.js:51:28)
```

app.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;

var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver: Resolver
});

loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);

export default App;
```

Comment: How about showing us your app.js?

Comment: Hi @karl added app.js in question.

Comment: There shouldn't be a `frontend/app.js` only a `frontend/app/app.js`. How did you generate the ember project? Might also be interesting to have a look at your `config/environment.js`

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help. Deleting the frontend directory and checking out a fresh frontend directory and installing packages resolved the issue. I guess there was some error in installing packages.